# Resolve an equation that uses remainders

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I wan to know how to solve this equation where $\rm\ D $ and $\rm\ k $ values are know and I want to find $x$:

$x (x\ mod\ k\ ) ^ 2  \rm\ mod\  k = D$

And I dont know  how to start and how to exactly the problem is expressed in math notation. I using the mod of remainder operation no the congruences.

I extract the equation analizing some ofuscated source code
the code that looks like

`if (x*((x % k) * (x % k))) % k == D  ...`

I put the code if i made a mistake traslating to math notation .

## update

Maybe is not computable after all. But i want to know the teory for the great good. The values are very big:

$\ k=$
    134908246421120481758163246661992595636170321686448474706440739628688109783740860298237556469237969452644490512779389250731193716102265810626226010445308778149257733945246516748118415698788521821626025173366644769118674263043277444473840006708507357109944794039692095527291233717252207868936434225226739116901

$\ D= $

5486124068793688683255936251187209270074392635932332070112001988456197381759672947165175699536362793613284725337872111744958183862744647903224103718245670299614498700710006264535590197791934024641512541262359795191593953928908168990292758500391456212260079471274317399924646987873523990414169975398570173

Comment: What is the order of precedence for the $\%$ sign versus multiplication?

Comment: In other words, is $a*b\% c*d$ interpreted as $(a*b)\%(c*d)$ or as $a*(b\%c)*d$, or as $((a*b)\%c)*d$?

Comment: is the same  that x*((x % k) * (x % k)) % k i edit

Comment: Still, is the middle parenthetical multiplied by the $x$ on the left first, or remainder-divided with the $k$ on the right first?

Comment: aja i think the correct is the same precedence and left to rigth, know i edit again , this is in python and i check against the values, but better is to not use parentesis because this code is valid in many languajes and maybe not have the same precedence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little tricky, because in math notation, we don't use the symbol $\mod{}$ to mean the same thing as the computer operator %.

However, it appears that we're starting with a number $x$, reducing it to its least positive residue modulo $k$, squaring the result, multiplying again by $x$, and then reducing modulo $k$ one more time.

If that's right, the the initial reduction modulo $k$ has no effect, and this is the same as just taking $x^3$ % $k$. In math, we would write

$$x^3\equiv D \pmod{k}$$

where the $\pmod{k}$ isn't applying to the $D$, but to the equivalence. A clearer way of writing it might be:

$$x^3\equiv_k D$$

Anyway, solving uniquely for $x$ isn't possible here, but you can narrow your options down somewhat. The most straightforward way would be to look at all the numbers $0,1, 2,\ldots k-1$, cube each one, reduce each cube modulo $k$, and see which ones equal $D$. Then you can say that the original $x$ must have been equivalent, modulo $k$, to one of those.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single solution, but instead very many solutions. But it is possible to give a partial description.

Firstly, the inner $\bmod k$ is actually redundant. This is because if we replace the inner mod by $x + ky$ for any multiple $y$ of $k$, then we have
$$\begin{align}
x (x \bmod k)^2 \bmod k &= x( x + ky)^2 \bmod k = x^3 + 2x^2ky + xk^2y^2 \bmod k \\ & x^3 + k(2x^2y + xky^2) \bmod k = x^3 \bmod k.
\end{align}$$

So adding or removing multiples to the inner mod doesn't change anything, and what you're really trying to do is solve
$$ x^3 \equiv D \bmod k.$$
The bad news is that actually solving this is a bit nontrivial, and not something that I know how to do well. Generically, the thought would be to factor $k$ and solve the cubic for each prime power factor. [This other question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673418/cube-roots-modulo-p) is exactly this problem for primes.

---

I will also note that there might be a good reason to computer inner mods *in the context of computers*, because multiplication is quicker on small numbers and large numbers might exceed limits of finite precision arithmetic. For example, if $x$ might have $10$ digits and one only has $15$ digits of accuracy, then computing $x^2$ and then modding out by a $5$ digit number would be much lossier than modding first, squaring, and then modding again. Finite precision arithmetic is tremendously annoying.